# Email separation

Tags: javascript

How do I split a string with multiple separators in JavaScript? I'm trying to split on both commas and spaces but, AFAIK, js's split function only supports one separator.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you just replace all spaces with commas and then split on commas

Answer (score 2):

The split function takes a regular expression.

```
> "Hello, world. How are you?".split(/[ ,]/);
[ 'Hello',
  '',
  'world.',
  'How',
  'are',
  'you?' ]
```

(You might want `[ ,]+` instead)